# How to generate multiple SSH public key and configure those on windows machine from gitbash?

Tags: linux, windows, git, ssh, ssh-keys

Let's first describe the problem that I've faced:

- I've two PC, one of them is the Windows machine and the other one is the Linux machine.
- I want to generate two SSH public key on both of these machines. One is for my GitHub account and the other one is for my GitLab account.
- I have used the following commands to generate the public SSH key which is perfectly work in my Linux machine but not in the Windows machine.

**Commands:**

**Step 1:** Generate SSH Key

```
ssh-keygen
```

**Step 2:** Write the directory and file name where I want to save the SSH key.

[ For my case, I've inserted the windows path in below ]

```
/c/Users/PC_USER_NAME/.ssh/id_rsa_hub
```

**Step 3:** Get the public key from the file

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa_hub.pub
```

These steps perfectly work on my Linux machine but on Windows, I saw the authentication error. How can I configure the SSH public key's?

Comment: This is on topic, and I have answered many similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the windows machine, you have to do one more configuration. Just follow the steps in below (if you're using the Git Bash):

1. Go to the .ssh directory `/c/Users/PC_USER_NAME/.ssh/`, click right mouse button and choose "Git Bash Here"
2. Create a file named "config" with the following command:

```
touch config
```

3. Now open the config file with the command:

```
nano config
```

4. Now write the following lines inside the config file

Let's assume you've created two files named `id_rsa_hub` for Github and `id_rsa_lab` for GitLab

```
# GITHUB
Host github.com
   HostName github.com
   PreferredAuthentications publickey
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_hub

# GITLAB
Host gitlab.com
   HostName gitlab.com
   PreferredAuthentications publickey
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_lab
```

Answer (score 1):

Try generating on Windows an SSH key with the [legacy format, in case the new OpenSSH one isn't fully recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309), using `-m PEM`:

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -P "" -f /c/Users/<yourLogin>/.ssh/id_rsa_hub
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -P "" -f /c/Users/<yourLogin>/.ssh/id_rsa_lab
```

Then declare your two keys in a `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host gh
 HostName github.com
 User git
 IdentityFile /c/Users/<yourLogin>/.ssh/id_rsa_hub  

Host gl
 HostName gitlab.com
 User git
 IdentityFile /c/Users/<yourLogin>/.ssh/id_rsa_lab  

Host *
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
```

Your SSH URL will be `gh:<user>/<repo>` or `gl:<user>/<repo>`